# Can we choose a particular interface when using raw sockets?

Tags: linux, raw-sockets

I'm building an application in linux that sends data only through a certain interface. Can I do that using raw sockets, maybe using the set socket options function?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "by force"? Unbuffered?

Comment: if we have two interfaces(let's say a wifi and ethernet), I need my packets to go through one of them(say wifi). Regardless.

Comment: So you are saying it would not be acceptable to send some packets over wifi and others over ethernet?

Comment: say I want all the packets to go through the ethernet link, so yes, that's exactly what I'm saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a socket you do it by IP. But hopefully your interfaces have different IP addresses. If so, you can just call [getifaddrs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs) first and find the address of the interface you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can bind a already open socket to given interface by using following.

1. Use bind on the socket.
2. Use setsockopt. Use option SO_BINDTODEVICE.

Comment: is this available in C#?